# Bot deployed on IIS Web server takes longer to respond than bot deployed on Azure

Tags: iis, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I created a simple bot with minimal/test business logic using Microsoft bot framework and successfully deployed it on premise on a IIS Server and registered the bot endpoint with bot connector service and enabled the directline channel.

client(DirectLine client) <=> bot connector service <=>  bot host(on Premise IIS server) . This takes around 7 sec in all to and from conversation.

But, if I change the architecture as

client(DirectLine client) <=> bot connector service <=>  bot host(Azure deployment). this takes around 2-3 seconds.

As my client requires the deployment to be OnPremise , How can I improve performance same as Azure deployment.

Comment: Have you checked the High-Speed Storage option when configuring the DirecLine channel? https://blog.botframework.com/2017/02/02/Direct-Line-performance-improvements/

Comment: Thanks for reply.Yes already done that.